# Got stuck with signing in

Tags: samsung

So i factory reset my J1 phone since it kept on turning itself on and off and then "The process com.google.process.gapps has stopped" "Google play services has stopped" kept on appearing, and when I was about to sign in with my existing g-mail account, it got stuck with Signing in...This can take a few minutes. I just don't know what to do with it anymore. I tried everything i saw on the net and none of them worked. I can't even use my phone. :(Your response will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advancse

Answer (score 0):

You can just skip the SetupWizard if you want by tapping each of the 4 corners of the screen in the next order:

1.`top-left`

2.`top-right`

3.`bottom-right`

4.`bottom-left`.